# How do I append to a json file in php and parse it into an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, parsing

I am trying to add to a .txt file in JSON format every time an account is created.

As you can see my code below:

```
<?php
        $myObj->username = $username;
        $myObj->password = $password;

        $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
        $stringJSON = $myJSON.",";
        print $stringJSON;

        $myfile = file_put_contents('UserJSON.txt', $stringJSON.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        fclose('UserJSON.txt');       
?>
```

I need to now read in this .txt in javascript and make each one an object
Here is what the .txt example looks like:

```
{"username":"User1@gmail.com","password":"pass"}
{"username":"User3@gmail.com","password":"pass"}
```

Here is my code to read in the txt file

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(myObj);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "UserJSON.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But it errors when trying to make it into an object because the txt file should be surrounded by "[" "]" otherwise it fails to parse the JSON. That being said, can I somehow remove the previous ending ] and append a new one on the end when another user is added to the JSON or should I be creating the object another way ?

Comment: You should probably just read the JSON on the PHP side, append to the object, then write it back to the file, then you don't have to mess with the text form.

Comment: @Herohtar how would I go about doing that ?

Comment: You'll need an array for your list of username/password objects, use `json_decode` after reading the file in PHP and work with that, then write it to the file in more or less the same way you are writing the single object now.

Comment: Method1. when you append json object, read all from txt and parse json and insert new json object and write all again. but it's good at CRUD but not good at performance. Method2. text file edit. open txt file and seek the position before ']' from the EOF and write the json string with ']'.

Comment: {"username":"User1@gmail.com","password":"pass"}
{"username":"User3@gmail.com","password":"pass"}  you dont have a comma, its not a valid JSON object, you must add [ {"a":"1"}, {"b":"2"}]  bracket and comma so you can parse that

Comment: It is maybe an example, but passing user passwords in plaintext is always a bad example!

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple exam. when this code runs, it will append.

```
$myobj->user = "aaa" ;
$myobj->pwd = "bbb" ;

$filename="jsonadd.txt" ;

$json = json_encode($myobj) ;
printf($json."\n") ;

if ( !file_exists($filename) ) {
    printf("file create.\n") ;
    $f=fopen($filename, "w+") ;
    fputs($f, "[\n") ;
    fputs($f, $json) ;
    fputs($f, "\n]") ;
    fclose($f) ;
} else {
printf("file open.\n") ;
    $f=fopen($filename, "r+") ;
    fseek($f, -1, SEEK_END) ;
    fputs($f, ",".$json) ;
    fputs($f, "\n]") ;
    fclose($f) ;
}
system("cat $filename") ;
```